# Need advice on pushState and onpopstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to not load all page content and to make the button back work i use `pushState` and `onpopstate` like this :

```
function get_page(args){
    ....
    $.ajax({ 

        url     : '/ajax/search?' + param  ,  type : 'get', 
        success : function(data) {   

                    $('#search_aj').html(data); 

                    window.history.pushState( { url: '/ajax/search?' + param  }
                    , "" , '/search?' + param  );
        },  
    });
}

window.onpopstate = function(e) {

    if ( e.state == null ){
        location.href = location.href ;
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({ url     : e.state.url , type : 'get', 
        success : function(data) {   
            $('#search_aj').html(data); 
        },      
    });     
};
```

It works but think my code is not good because i repeat the success code in Ajax and if i make change in one i have to change it in other one.
and the code `( e.state == null )` is best way to get back to the first page?

Is there some advice you can give me to enhance my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many similar small requests in your script, you can manage it in a function that will do the job.

```js
function makeRequest(url, successHandler) {
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#search_aj').html(data);

    successHandler && successHandler();
  });
}

function get_page(args) {
  //...
  var historyURL = '/search?' + param;
  var reqURL = '/ajax' + historyURL;

  makeRequest(reqURL, function() {
    window.history.pushState({
      url: reqURL
    }, '', historyURL);
  });
}

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
  if (e.state)
    makeRequest(e.state.url);
  else
    location.href = location.href;
});
```

```html
Nothing here, sorry.
```

jQuery is designed to write less code so you may use [`.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) instead of `.ajax` to make `GET request`. Also it's good practice to use jQuery [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) or native [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method to subscribe to DOM events, so that your code didn't mess with other scripts event subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to call on success of your ajax calls. That will make it a little more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
function get_page(args){
    ....
    $.ajax({ 

        url     : '/ajax/search?' + param  ,  type : 'get', 
        success : function(data) {   
            populateSearch(data);
                window.history.pushState( { url: '/ajax/search?' + param  }, "" , '/search?' + param  );

        },  
    }); 

}




window.onpopstate = function(e) {

    if ( e.state == null ){
        location.href = location.href ;
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({ url     : e.state.url , type : 'get', 
        success : function(data) {   
            populateSearch(data);
        },      

    });     

};

function populateSearch(data)
{
    $('#search_aj').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) to reduce the amount of places that you are needing to repeat code.

**Note:** This does effect all ajax calls in the file or any file that is included with it.

As far as `( e.state == null )` being the best. I can not really think of a better way without much context of the application